# install python-sophia database bindings with pypy

Tags: pypy

I have such a problem on install sophia database bindings https://github.com/doukremt/python-sophia with pypy in virtualenv (native python works fine)

```
    import sophia
  File "/home/se7en/.virtualenvs/pypyenv/site-packages/sophia/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from _sophia import *
ImportError: unable to load extension module '/home/se7en/.virtualenvs/pypyenv/site-packages/_sophia.pypy-18.so': /home/se7en/.virtualenvs/pypyenv/site-packages/_sophia.pypy-18.so: undefined symbol: PyLong_FromSize_t
```

please help to fix

Comment: Seems you didn't compile `_sophia` using PyPy's own includes.  Try something like `pip install sophia` from within the virtualenv.

Comment: pip install sophia, does not help(

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see `pypy-1.8` in your paste.  You need to upgrade to a version of PyPy that is less incredibly old.

Answer (score 0):

you may take a look at website of sphia get section, where python bindings are listed and compatibility with latest sp api, sppy is cffi based wrapper and you may use it with pypy.

Regards.